# Setting label in Java button listener

Tags: java

How can I avoid so many `if` statements?

```
//Radio Button toggle


if (five.isSelected() == true) {
            one.setSelected(false);

    private class JButtonListner implements ActionListener {

//As my code has 4 options (1,5,+,-) to change the label, i have done 4 if else statments. is it possible to avoid such mess?


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(plus) && five.isSelected() == true) {
                count += 5;
                label.setText(Integer.toString(count));

            } else if (e.getSource().equals(minus) && five.isSelected() == true) {
                count -= 5;
                label.setText(Integer.toString(count));

            } else if (e.getSource().equals(minus) && one.isSelected() == true) {
                count --;
                label.setText(Integer.toString(count));

            } else if (e.getSource().equals(plus) && one.isSelected() == true) {
                count++;
                label.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/181126/revisions) to a different one that describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to see more of the code since `one`, `five`, `plus` and `minus` give `NullPointerException`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      int value = five.isSelected() ? 5 : 1;
      if (event.getSource().equals(plus)) {
                count += value;      
      } else if (event.getSource().equals(minus)) {
                count -= value;
      } 
      label.setText(Integer.toString(count));
}
```

Since you only have 2 `RadioButton`, that would mean that the `value` could only be two values, either `5` or `1`. This can be done by line two, you are asking if `five.isSelected()`, `if(five.isSelected()) { return 5; } else { return 1; }`. Also there is no need to say `five.isSelected() == true`, because the `if` already asks if it is true so `five.isSelected()` is sufficient.

Now you dont need to plus/minus with `5` or `1`, but only check `plus` or `minus`.

And you set the text each time `count` has changed, so this can just be done after the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code is not complete, so I might make assumptions where something is missing.

---

`if (five.isSelected()) == true)` is redundant. Just write `if (five.isSelected())` instead.

---

Be careful with the indentation. Wrong indentation can hurt readability:

```
    one.setSelected(false);

    private class JButtonListner implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

---

Use local variables to abstract details and increase readability:

```
            bool plusFive = e.getSource().equals(plus) && five.isSelected();
            bool minusFive = e.getSource().equals(minus) && five.isSelected();
            bool plusOne = e.getSource().equals(plus) && one.isSelected();
            bool minusOne = e.getSource().equals(minus) && one.isSelected();

            if (plusFive) {
                count += 5;
            } else if (minusFive) {
                count -= 5;
            } else if (plusOne) {
                count += 1;
            } else if (minusOne) {
                count -= 1;
            }
```

---

You only need to write this once, as it is done in all of the above cases.

```
            label.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```

Comment: I have cleaned my code a bit thanks to you but will explain better. Or maybe for next time theres a way to upload the jframe itself? So, The radio buttons are the chosen values (1,5) and the buttons are  the + and -.

Answer (score 0):

The point is:

If you make the decisions (if-statements) what to do far beyond the elements that make the difference (JButtons) you have no chance to avoid additonal decision constructs.

If the JButton have a 1:1 relationship to the numbers you may store them as "user data" at the JButton (e.g. setActionCommand(...)). Then you may come up with following:

```
buttonMinus1.setActionCommand("-1");
buttonPlus1.setActionCommand("1");
buttonPlus5.setActionCommand("5");
...
```

In your listener you then only have one line:

```
count -= Integer.parseInt(((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand());
```

This looks a little bit ugly but it is the Swing way. Other frameworks do not work with the String-Type. They often work with the Object-type (Vaadin: button.setData(...), JavaFX: radioButton.setUserData(...), etc.).

Nevertheless: the trick is to make the decision at the origin if possible. In your case in the buttons.

You may also have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533356/is-there-a-way-to-store-data-in-a-jbutton

One big advantage ist:

You are able to add new Buttons (plus 300??) without the need of enhancing any if cascades.